# invalid argument exception when creating ChromeWebElement using a string

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I create a `ChromeWebElement` using a `string` at runtime , I get

`The best overloaded method match for 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeWebElement.ChromeWebElement(OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver, string)' has some invalid argumentsResult message:`

```
    public class Browser {

           public static dynamic driver,d;

          public Browser(BrowserDriver browserDriver, FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
         _browserDriver = browserDriver;
         driver = _browserDriver._driver;
         _featureContext = featureContext;
         _featureContext.Add("driver", driver);

    }

      [StepArgumentTransformation]

      public ChromeWebElement convertToWebElement(string c)
      {
        d = _featureContext.Get<IWebDriver>("driver");
          return new ChromeWebElement(Browser.d,c);

      }
```

According to the [this](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeWebElement__ctor.htm) , the constructor only takes two arguments `ChromeDriver` and `string` . So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line

```
new ChromeWebElement(Browser.d,c);
```

in this case

- `c` is string
- `Browser.d` is dynamic (declared here `public static dynamic d;`)

but the constructor of `ChromeWebElement` requires:

```
public ChromeWebElement(
    ChromeDriver parent,
    string elementId
)
```

Change declaration of `d` to

```
private static IWebDriver d;
```

or even better, remove that declaration and use

```
  public ChromeWebElement convertToWebElement(string elementId)
  {
      IWebDriver parent = _featureContext.Get<IWebDriver>("driver");
      return new ChromeWebElement(parent, elementId);
  }
```

Comment: If I change that , I get `cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver' (CS1503)`

Comment: use `_featureContext.Add("driver", _browserDriver._driver);` and show us type of `_browserDriver._driver`

Comment: It is determined at runtime , thats why I had `dynamic`

Comment: `d` in your case is not determined at runtime

Comment: When I used `ChromeDriver parent = _featureContext.Get<ChromeDriver>("driver");` and `return new ChromeWebElement(parent, c);` I get the correct error . I was actually using `EventFiringWebDriver` . I change it to `ChromeWebDriver` now . So  wrong code was this `d = _featureContext.Get<IWebDriver>("driver");` . I needed to capture the "dynamic" driver with correct `<T>`